# Mapping a BsonArray to a List<> in a POCO

Tags: c#, mongodb

I was using [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150928175408/http://www.drdobbs.com/database/mongodb-with-c/240151668?pgno=1) to learn about mapping documents in a Mongo database to POCO objects.

My documents are setup like this:

```
{
  "VehicleEntry" : [
      {
          "BatteryStatus" : "GOOD",
          "VehicleStatus" : "PASSED"
      }, 
      {
          "BatteryStatus" : "GOOD",
          "VehicleStatus" : "PASSED"
      }
  ],
  "project_id" : "1234"
}
```

The main thing to notice about this is that I have an array inside of each document called VehicleEntry. I have setup POCOs to match the documents like this:

```
public class VehicleEntry : MongoEntity
{
    [BsonElement("@Date")]
    public String Date { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("@Time")]
    public String Time { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("@Vin")]
    public String Vin { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("@Year")]
    public String Year { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("@Body")]
    public String Body { get; set; }

    [BsonExtraElements]
    public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleDataUpload : MongoEntity
{
    public VehicleDataUpload()
    {
        VehicleEntries = new List<VehicleEntry>();
    }

    [BsonElement("project_id")]
    public String ProjectId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("VehicleEntry")]
    public List<VehicleEntry> VehicleEntries { get; set; }

    [BsonExtraElements]
    public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }
}
```

To test this, I wrote one simple line that pulls for the first document found with a given project identifier:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<VehicleDataUpload>("vehicleCollection");
var firstProj = collection.AsQueryable().Where(i => i.ProjectId.Equals("myProjIdentifier")).First();
```

However, when I run it I get the following exception:

> Additional information: An error occurred while deserializing the VehicleEntries property of class CARSMongoTest.VehicleDataUpload: Cannot deserialize a 'List' from BsonType 'Document'.

I think this is pretty straight forward, as the type of `VehicleEntry` cannot be converted to a `List<>` object, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm a little confused why it says type 'Document' in the error message, when it should treat `VehicleEntry` as an Array type.

How can I map the array to a property of the POCO?

**EDIT**
I have tried changing VehicleEntry so it doesn't extend from MongoEntity, but the error still persists.

Comment: You have a single Document `VehicleDataUpload` that you store in the database with a collection of `VehicleEntries`. I think the problem is that `VehicleEntry` inherits from `MongoEntity` making it a document instead of a simple class.

Comment: @jvanrhyn so are you suggesting `VehicleEntry` shouldn't inherit from MongoEntity? I think that would make sense, let me test it and see.

Comment: That didn't work, because it still says it cannot deserialize a List<> from type Document.

Comment: Just to check: are you sure the documents in your collection look like the sample you posted? The error implies that they're not.

Comment: @Peter I realize my sample doesn't include date/time/vin/year, etc, but they are all in the document. I have also tried changing the map to have `List<BsonDocument>` instead of `List<VehicleEntry>` so it sounds like the issue really is with the type. I'm not sure why an array is being considered as one document though?

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying when you change the type of the property `VehicleDataUpload.VehicleEntries` to be `List<BsonDocument>` it works?

Comment: No it doesn't work. I made an interesting discovery, will answer. I'm so dumb.

Comment: @Peter you were right. I had a really unlucky coincidence that my test project didn't have an array, but a single VehicleEntry. This code is fine. I will have to look into, or post a separate question, to see if I can force that field to become a List<> even for a single document.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Any ideas for still making a List out of one item? I think I have to start by looking at BsonClassMap, instead of mapping via attributes like I do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I realized that the reason this was failing was because of an error on my end. Most of our projects will have multiple vehicle entries, but by chance the one I was testing with only had one in the XML, so the deserialization converted it to a Document, not to a BsonArray.

The above code will work, assuming the `VehicleEntry` field is in fact of type BsonArray, the driver will map it to a List object.