# How can I map a 'null' reference to the default constructor from MongoDB to a POCO?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am mapping MongoDB documents to C# objects (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34729851/3131147) for some background) and everything works fine, however I'm starting to find some entries that are null. The reason being the XML previously just had `<VehicleEntry></VehicleEntry>` tags so it was inserted as 'null' into the array in the BsonDocument.

I can understand that this would be expected behavior, but when I map it to my `VehicleEntry` class that I wrote, it shows up as a null object. In my mapped class I have listed a bunch of BsonDefaultValues and even added a default constructor, but it still appears that if the value is 'null' in the database it will create a 'null' reference object.

How can I set this up to match a null reference to an object with all default values?

Answer (score 1):

If you create your own BsonSerializers and assign it to the VehicleEntry type you'll then be able to say if the value is null then return a `default(VehicleEntry)`

```
[TestFixture]
public class StackQuestionTest
{
    [Test]
    public void GivenABsonDocumentWithANullForAnPossibleEmbeddedDocument_When_ThenAnInstanceIsSetAsTheEmbeddedDocument()
    {
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new VehicleEntryBsonSerializationProvider());

        var document = new BsonDocument()
        {
            {"OtherProperty1", BsonString.Create("12345")},
            {"OtherProperty2", BsonString.Create("67890")},
            {"VehicleEntry", BsonNull.Value},
        };

        var rootObject = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(document);

        Assert.That(rootObject.OtherProperty1, Is.EqualTo("12345"));
        Assert.That(rootObject.OtherProperty2, Is.EqualTo("67890"));
        Assert.That(rootObject.VehicleEntry, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(rootObject.VehicleEntry.What, Is.EqualTo("Magic"));
    }
}

public class VehicleEntrySerializer : BsonClassMapSerializer<VehicleEntry>
{
    public override VehicleEntry Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        if (context.Reader.GetCurrentBsonType() == BsonType.Null)
        {
            context.Reader.ReadNull();

            return new VehicleEntry();
        }

        return base.Deserialize(context, args);
    }

    public VehicleEntrySerializer(BsonClassMap classMap) : base(classMap)
    {

    }
}

public class VehicleEntryBsonSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(VehicleEntry))
        {
            BsonClassMap bsonClassMap = BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(type);

            return new VehicleEntrySerializer(bsonClassMap);
        }

        return null;
    }
}


public class RootObject
{
    public string OtherProperty1 { get; set; }

    public string OtherProperty2 { get; set; }

    public VehicleEntry VehicleEntry { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleEntry
{
    public string What { get; set; } = "Magic";
}
```

See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/serialization/

Comment: `public void GivenABsonDocumentWithANullForAnPossibleEmbeddedDocument_When_ThenAnInstanceIsSetAsTheEmbeddedDocument()` Nice.

Comment: `public void TestWhatEverIsInQuestion()`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change your LINQ to only return values that aren't null in the list:

```
var results = collection.AsQueryable()
   .Where(v => v.ProjectName.Equals("input")
   .SelectMan(v => v.VehicleEntries)
   .Where(i => i != null)
   .ToList();
```

This does not solve the problem of having the null value there, but it presents it from being returned in any results and avoids NPEs when displaying the data.